# How to use RabbitMQ in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, rabbitmq

Didn't found a single thing about how to use RabbitMQ in VB

It is possible to make changes to some extend, to make it look like C#

```
Dim factory = New ConnectionFactory() : With factory
  .HostName = "localhost"
End With

Using connection = factory.CreateConnection()
  Using channel = connection.CreateModel()

  ...
  ...

  End Using
End Using
```

And I already have checked that there are no problems with sending messages or declaring queues, but what about usage of consumer?

In C# Consumer looks like:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;

            ...
            ...

            channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false, false);
        };
```

But how this supposed to look in VB?
Already tried this kind of stuff:

```
Dim consumer As EventingBasicConsumer = New EventingBasicConsumer(channel)
AddHandler consumer.Received, AddressOf ConsumerReceived

Private Sub ConsumerReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Dim Test = ""
End Sub
```

Consumer is created without a problem, but there are no reaction on event

Is there some kind of work around, manual how to use RabbitMQ with VB or maybe I am simply missing something?

Comment: I upvoted your question and I read it. But my only hint were to use an online converter.

Comment: People on So have a strict diet, please do not add salt directly into your question. They may have an intolerence. You can instead ask how to improve your question. I see Nothing wrong in your question, but i'm not an expert. Only a low rep passing by.

Comment: Sadly, online converter can't understand what to do with `converter.Received`. I simply don't believe that no one tried to use RabbitMQ on VB before :( There must be something

Comment: The right thing to do in this circumstance is to adapt and start using c#, which is a far less cumbersome programming language. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question really seems to be how to assign an anonymous function as an event handler in VB.NET. It's not the same question as why the event handler isn't getting called.

But I think what you're looking for may be this:

```
AddHandler consumer.Received, Sub(consumer as IBasicConsumer, ea as BasicDeliverEventArgs)
    Dim body = ea.Body
    '...  
    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false, false)
End Sub
```

Or you could do as you are and put the event handler in a separate method. (I lean toward that just because it's easier to read and follow.)

In your VB.NET method you're casting the event sender and args as `object` and `EventArgs`. The arguments can be cast to those types since everything is an object and `BasicDeliverEventArgs` inherits from `EventArgs`. But in this case you'd want to cast more specifically so that you can access the properties you need.

```
Private Sub ConsumerReceived(ByVal sender As IBasicConsumer, ByVal e As BasicDeliverEventArgs)
  Dim Test = ""
End Sub
```

The easiest thing (if it's an option) is just to switch to C#. That makes code samples easier to work with. I held on to VB.NET for a while. No idea why - it didn't take long to adjust to C# and I quickly came to prefer it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your response and for example. Didn't even considered this way. Didn't worked out on first attempt, but `Console.ReadKey` made a magic. I also think that C# is way better, but for my situation, sadly, not an option